# Determinants of exact sequence of bundles

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. Let $$0\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow G\rightarrow 0$$ be an exact sequence of holomorphic bundles over $X$. Show that $\det F\cong\det E\otimes\det G$.

I thought to try by associating the corresponding sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. If the sequence splits (like it is the case in the real setting), it is simple. In general it does not split, however we have splitting at the level of stalks i.e. $F_x\cong E_x\oplus G_x$ for every $x\in X$. If $\phi$, $\psi$ and $\tau$ are corresponding transition maps that is e.g. $\phi (U\cap V):\mathcal{O}(U\cap V) ^r\rightarrow E(U\cap V)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(U\cap V) ^r$, then at every point we shall have matrix for $\psi _x$ is block diagonal with blocks $\phi _x$ and something else that should give determinant isomorphic to that of  $G$. How we can relate the transition functions of bundles forming an exact sequence and use it to prove the claim?
To answer the last question, for simplicity one can assume $G$ is subbundle of $E$. (Then the first question becomes why $\det G \cong \det F/E$ )

Comment: Can you do it if $X$ is a point? If yes, then do the same over every point. If not, do it over a point!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It's important, of course, to say "can you do it *naturally*"... One can always pick a splitting over a point, but that would be a crime against nature.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I can do it over a point, as I have described. However only over a point since I cannot define a map on any neighbourhood. If the sheaves were flasque, then it could go, but they are not.

Comment: You do it over a point by picking coordinates. What breaks if you do that over a chart? It's going to be difficult to pick coodinates in a nonsmooth way....

Comment: (In factm if you reduce to a small open set $U$, what you you have is a $U$-point, and the computation which proved the statement over a single point works mutatis  mutandi for projective modules over the ring of functions over $U$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transition functions for $F$ are a block upper triangular matrix with top left block the transition functions for $E$ and bottom right block the transition functions for $G$. (The top right is some garbage we don't care about.) It is a linear algebra fact that the determinant of such a matrix is the product of the determinants of its diagonal blocks. Since the transition function of a tensor product of line bundles is the product of their transition functions, this proves the claim.

Comment: I am not sure this is true. Since in the holomorphic setting there might be more non isomorphic $G$ which fit into the exact sequence $0\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow *\rightarrow 0$. And even if it was isomorphic I think we would get rather different maps. (in the case of one dimensional e.g. trivial bundle is given by any maps $s_\alpha /s_\beta$ where $s_\alpha :U_\alpha\rightarrow\mathbb{C} ^*$ for each $\alpha$ )

Comment: What I've written is literally what it means to fit into an exact sequence (when you pick an open cover such that all three bundles trivialize over it). And you're right that $G$ can be different, but $\text{det}(G)$ will be the same!

Comment: Hmm so are you saying that given sufficently small $U$ then $F|U=E|U\oplus G|U$? My definition was that corresponding sheaves were exact. The second definition doesn't trivially imply the first, or does it ?

Comment: The transition functions for $F$ are not diagonal - they are upper triangular. For an explicit reference, see p68 of Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that it is not block diagonal but upper triangular diagonal. I checked your reference, I didn't know that we can write the matrices like this.

Comment: @MikeMiller How did you get the transition function?